# Как спарсить JSON в массив java обьектов Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

Есть сайт [ссылка](https://api.publicapis.org/entries) для этого сайта как model создать ?

Comment: Alt+Insert -> new Class и дальше заполняете по необходимости

Comment: Для таких целей очень удобен сайт www.jsonschema2pojo.org, но в вашем примере очень большая строка, не получается обработать. Здесь вроде бы нормально получается: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь [www.jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

```
public class Entry {

@SerializedName("API")
@Expose
private String aPI;
@SerializedName("Description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("Auth")
@Expose
private String auth;
@SerializedName("HTTPS")
@Expose
private Boolean hTTPS;
@SerializedName("Cors")
@Expose
private String cors;
@SerializedName("Link")
@Expose
private String link;
@SerializedName("Category")
@Expose
private String category;

}


public class Response{

@SerializedName("count")
@Expose
private Integer count;
@SerializedName("entries")
@Expose
private List<Entry> entries = null;

}
```

Comment: это мне не помогло, получаю следующую ошибку: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ 

Ссылка собственно на ошибку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798314/retrofit-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2-path?noredirect=1&lq=1