# Retrofit Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, gson

Я знаю, что это не первый раз, когда кто-то спрашивал про эту проблему, но с Retrofit2 я не могу найти правильное решение моей проблемы. Получаю следующую ошибку: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Base_URL [данные беру из этого сайт](https://api.publicapis.org/entries)

Interface:

```
 public interface RetrofitService {

@GET("entries/count")
Call<List<JsonModel>> getJsonList();
```

}

StartApplication:

```
public class StartApplication extends Application {

private final String BASE_URL = "https://api.publicapis.org/";
private RetrofitService service;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    service = initRetrofit();
}

public static StartApplication get(Context context) {

    return (StartApplication) context.getApplicationContext();  
}

public RetrofitService getRetrofitClient(){ 
    return service;
}

private RetrofitService initRetrofit() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(RetrofitService.class);
}
```

}

Собственно метод:

```
 private void setRequest() {
    RetrofitService service = StartApplication.get(this).getRetrofitClient();
    Call<List<JsonModel>> call = service.getJsonList();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<JsonModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<JsonModel>> call, Response<List<JsonModel>> response) {
 }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<JsonModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Model JsonModel:

```
public class JsonModel {

@SerializedName("API")
@Expose
private String aPI;
@SerializedName("Description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("Auth")
@Expose
private String auth;
@SerializedName("HTTPS")
@Expose
private String hTTPS;
@SerializedName("Cors")
@Expose
private String cors;
@SerializedName("Link")
@Expose
private String link;
@SerializedName("Category")
@Expose
private String category;
```

//Getter and Setter

CountModel:

```
public class CountModel {
@SerializedName("count")
@Expose
private int count;
@SerializedName("entries")
@Expose
private List<Map.Entry> entries = null;
```

Подскажите как исправить ?

[Как спарсить JSON в массив java обьектов Retrofit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798175/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-java-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-retrofit?noredirect=1#comment1260499_798175)

Answer (score 1):

Вам API отвечает не массивом, но объектом, содержащим массив и его размер.

Создайте такую модель и именно её укажите в ретрофите:

```
public class CountModel {

    private int count;
    private List<JsonModel> entries;
}
```

```
public interface RetrofitService {

    @GET("entries/count")
    Call<CountModel> getJsonList();
}
```

```
Call<CountModel> call = service.getJsonList();
```

Comment: Добавил, далее получаю след ошибку: ссылка на ошибку.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798393/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-interface-method-java-lang-ob

Comment: @TheSusanin, ответил вам там. Вы просто невнимательно код из моего ответа скопировали. У вас не массив, а один объект

Comment: Делал, как вы посоветовали. Теперь получаю след ошибку: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to example.cwpo18.CountModel 

Ссылка на код (код изменен) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798393/java-lang-classcastexception-java-util-arraylist-cannot-be-cast-to-example-cwpo

Comment: @TheSusanin, вы зря кастуете список объектов к вмещающему оный объекту - в этом просто нет смысла. Просто удалите эту строку. И будьте внимательнее при исправдении кода - эта строчка должна была быть изменена или удалена при рефакторинге